# no se ven las url de mi sitio, osea si les hago click derecho no me deja abrirlas en otra pestaña?

Tags: .net, web, imagen, bootstrap-4, url

este es el codigo de mis imagenes:

```
<div class="thumb imgbox">
     <img src="../Content/img/destination/PROMO1-01.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

la imagen carga correctamente, pero me piden que sea vea su dirección, como cuando en otros sitios das click derecho y la ves en otra página  la descargas

Comment: Revisa las clases `thumb` y `imgbox` o pon su contenido aquí, editando la pregunra

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer una imagen como un link, debes hacer lo siguiente, que es poner la imagen como el contenido de un link:

```
<div class="thumb imgbox">
  <a href="../Content/img/destination/PROMO1-01.jpg">
    <img src="../Content/img/destination/PROMO1-01.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Tienes la información [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp)